# "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" from easy_install

Tags: python, macos, easy-install

I have had a strange error today when I tried to upgrade some of my python apps (aka pip and aws clt) and received the following error:

```
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 31
    continue
           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Then I tried running `easy_install --version` and received the same error. I have all three of my computers (Macbook Pro, iMac, and Mac Pro) running the same commands, only my Macbook Pro has this error (and all of them share the identical python version and apps). I like to know what might be the cause of this error message.

P.S. I have tried to copy the "/usr/bin/easy_install" file from one computer to another and received the same error message.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I was not trying to run an application, I merely ran the easy_install command. It's the easy_install came with OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just my guessing. I have signed up for Apple Developer programer and used a beta test version of OS X. I then turned off the developer mode and returned to the ordinary Yosemite but the funny part is I cannot use easy_install afterward. I think turning off the developer mode is the same as turning off easy_install. I am not entirely sure if that is true but you can give it a try. Either reinstall the OS X, or simply turn the developer mode back on.

Comment: Interesting. LOL, is there a way to get east_install working without reinstalling everything or enrolling in the pre-release program again?

Comment: You could of course manually copy the easy_install from your python folder if you do a manual installation of `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py`, the easy_install is located at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin`, make sure to match your system python version to 3.4

Answer (score 1):

> I am not really an expert on this so please consider this with caution ;)

I also run into this error recently and I think it is due to having multiple versions of *easy_install* and(!) multiple versions of *python* available.

in my case I have the following versions available:

```
easy_install
easy_install-2.6
easy_install-2.7
easy_install-3.4
```

after running

```
sudo easy_install-2.7 pip
```

I was able to (re)-install *pip*.

**notes:**

- easy_install launches `#!/usr/bin/python`
- in my case `/usr/bin/python` is a symlink to version 3.4 of python
- easy_install is probably written for python 2.x and fails with error *"inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"* when using python 3.x

Answer (score -3):

i I suggest you to upload the code.

it look like you don't use the correct tabulation

something like that:

```
for i in range(0,5):
   print i
    print i**2
```

Comment: If you don't know already, easy_install is a pre-installed feature in OSX... There is no code involved.

Comment: It's funny how he didn't even use the correct tabulation in his example...@AeroWang